# Java - Get every webpage associated with domain name programmatically

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to make a program where a user enters a URL, and the program responds with every web page associated under that domain name. Right now, I'm using Jsoup to get every `<a href>` link, but that does not always cover every web page on a site if the site changes pages through AngularJS or something else. Any advice on how best to do this?

Comment: Every web page? Many pages are dynamic, generated only based on input from the user. Also, what about pages that are not linked from the original web page?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jsoup for this.  Just navigate to the host's `robots.txt`

https://stackoverflow.com/robots.txt

And find the `sitemap.xml`.

```
Sitemap: /sitemap.xml
```

In the case of SO, [theirs is cached](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180660/335825) on Google:

[cache:https://stackoverflow.com/sitemap.xml](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fsitemap.xml&aq=f&oq=cache%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fsitemap.xml&aqs=chrome.0.57j58j60.1207j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

This will have all of the links the website wants to be publicly available.  Or in the case of SO, a list of additional site maps to scan through.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/sitemap-questions-0.xml      
https://stackoverflow.com/sitemap-questions-1.xml 
https://stackoverflow.com/sitemap-questions-2.xml 
https://stackoverflow.com/sitemap-questions-3.xml 
https://stackoverflow.com/sitemap-questions-4.xml 
https://stackoverflow.com/sitemap-questions-5.xml 
https://stackoverflow.com/sitemap-questions-6.xml
....
```