# Getting sub links of a URL using jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

Consider a URl www.example.com it may have plenty numbers of links ,some may be internal and other may be external.I want to get a list of all the sub links ,not even the sub-sub links but only sub link.
E.G if there are four links as follows

```
1)www.example.com/images/main
2)www.example.com/data
3)www.example.com/users
4)www.example.com/admin/data
```

Then out of the four only 2 and 3 are of use as they are sub links not the sub-sub and so on links .Is there a way to achieve it through j-soup..If this could not be achieved through j-soup then one can introduce me with some other java API.
Also note that it should be a link of the parent Url which is initially sent(i.e. www.example.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i can understand a sub-link can contain one slash you can attempt with this with counting the number of slashes for example :

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("www.example.com/images/main");
list.add("www.example.com/data");
list.add("www.example.com/users");
list.add("www.example.com/admin/data");
```

---

```
for(String link : list){
    if((link.length() - link.replaceAll("[/]", "").length()) == 1){
        System.out.println(link);
    }
}
```

`link.length()`: count the number of characters
`link.replaceAll("[/]", "").length()` : count the number of slashes

If the difference equal to one then right link else no.

---

**EDIT**

> How will i scan the whole website for sub links?

The answer for this with the **robots.txt** file or [Robots exclusion standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard), so in this it define all the sub-links of the web site for example https://stackoverflow.com/robots.txt, so the idea is, to read this file and you can extract the sub-links from this web-site here is a piece of code that can help you :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    //Your web site
    String website = "http://stackoverflow.com";
    //We will read the URL https://stackoverflow.com/robots.txt
    URL url = new URL(website + "/robots.txt");

    //List of your sub-links
    List<String> list;

    //Read the file with BufferedReader
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()))) {
        String subLink;
        list = new ArrayList<>();

        //Loop throw your file
        while ((subLink = in.readLine()) != null) {

            //Check if the sub-link is match with this regex, if yes then add it to your list
            if (subLink.matches("Disallow: \\/\\w+\\/")) {
                list.add(website + "/" + subLink.replace("Disallow: /", ""));
            }else{
                System.out.println("not match");
            }
        }
    }

    //Print your result
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

This will show you :

> [https://stackoverflow.com/posts/, https://stackoverflow.com/posts?,
>   https://stackoverflow.com/search/, https://stackoverflow.com/search?,
>   https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/, https://stackoverflow.com/feeds?,
>   https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/,
>   https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered?, https://stackoverflow.com/u/,
>   https://stackoverflow.com/messages/, https://stackoverflow.com/ajax/,
>   https://stackoverflow.com/plugins/]

Here is a [Demo about the regex that i use](https://regex101.com/r/EXdA26/1).

Hope this can help you.

Comment: But how will i scan the whole website for sub links

Comment: Your implementation will work after i will get all the internal links in the website

Comment: check my edit @javafan the idea is to read the **robots.txt** it contain all the information of the web-site, so you can extract the sub-links from there

Comment: can i know why you removed the accepted answer @javafan ?

Comment: Sorry i didn't knew that we cannot accept two answers

Comment: no, if the the other answer help you you should to marked it like an accepted answer @javafan i asked just to know what is the true solution that's all so can you answer me?

Comment: I think(Rahul's answer) could be the correct answer but now i have found some bugs in the code i.e. it never comes to an end and ,2 it always prints the same link again and again.

Comment: also one should also have a look on www.anysite.com/sitemap.xml it also worked for me.And i am guiding you should have a look at it.It contains all the internal links of a site ,but the problem is some sites do and allow access to it e.g. google,stackoverflow,facebook etc

Comment: yes @javafan i know about this file, i avoid it because it is a little complected to parse not much but it take a little time but it still a right solution for your problem

Answer (score 1):

To scan the links on the web page you can use JSoup library.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

class read_data {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("**your_url**").get();
            Elements links = doc.select("a");
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Element link : links) {
                list.add(link.attr("abs:href"));
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }
    }
}
```

**list** can be used as suggested in the previous answer.

---

The code for reading all the links on a website is given below. I have used `http://stackoverflow.com/` for illustration. I would recommend you to go through company's [terms of use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terms_of_service) before scraping it's website.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class readAllLinks {

    public static Set<String> uniqueURL = new HashSet<String>();
    public static String my_site;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        readAllLinks obj = new readAllLinks();
        my_site = "stackoverflow.com";
        obj.get_links("http://stackoverflow.com/");
    }

    private void get_links(String url) {
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Elements links = doc.select("a");
            links.stream().map((link) -> link.attr("abs:href")).forEachOrdered((this_url) -> {
                boolean add = uniqueURL.add(this_url);
                if (add && this_url.contains(my_site)) {
                    System.out.println(this_url);
                    get_links(this_url);
                }
            });

        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }

    }
}
```

You will get list of all the links in `uniqueURL` field.

Comment: thanks for your help but let me tell you that i dont want to get links simply on a web page i wants to get links of the whole website.

Comment: you can see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32299871/java-get-every-webpage-associated-with-domain-name-programmatically). Let me know if that does not work for you.

Comment: I just tried this for few sites: `your_url/sitemap.xml`. Let me know if it works

Comment: i tried for stack overflow but it doest work for it.But when i tried it on my site it worked

Comment: I have edited the answer, hope this helps, accept it if it does help you.